Why does lottery write "in trust" on winner's cheque?
I never saw a lottery pay cheque to the order of winner "in trust", before this news on Aug. 21 2024. Why not just pay to the order of "JAMES B."?  Why add "in trust"?

I tried to do research. Page 145 defines trust

When a person has rights which he is bound to exercise upon behalf of another or for the accomplishment of some particular purpose he is said to have those rights in trust for that other or for that purpose and he is called a trustee.


They could have a living trust already set up. They may have set up an irrevocable trust to place the winnings into.

@JonCuster your comment went over my head. "living trust"? "irrevocable trust"?

Roger that. There is a tag for trusts on this SE to search on

Given this is referencing the BC Lotto Corp, maybe tag it with British Columbia and/or Canada (as we do not pay taxes on lottery winnings)

Also note that it's a fake cheque. It doesn't matter what you write on it from a legal or financial point of view.

The article states that he's accepting the money on behalf of a group that purchased the tickets together. Using a Trust or LLC can let the members remain anonymous if the lottery allows it. In some cases it may reduce taxes before the money is distributed - though this is a Canadian lottery so I wouldn't expect these winnings to be taxed.

This is probably it, especially considering this language is not typical for Lotto Max. Here is another story about winners with "In Trust" on the cheque, and it explicitly says in the story that they set up a trust for their winnings.

Important point: That's thing he's holding is not a real check that will get deposited. It is purely symbolic for purposes of the photo. Note that it's also made out to James B. rather than a full name.
Without knowing the details of that particular lottery, it is also possible that the lottery is, in fact, going to hold the money in trust and pay out a smaller amount each year for some number of years. That is fairly common, since it lets the lottery take advantage of investment gains on that money in the meantime, such that the actual cost to them is less than the nominal total. Spreading out the payments may also have tax advantages for the winner, so this isn't necessarily a bad thing, though it does make the stated value of the prize somewhat misleading. Always read the fine print, and understand the trade-offs that may be offered to you.

You should perhaps clarify that giant checks can be real, but this particular giant check is not since it is missing required elements such as the name of the bank, the account number, and the signature of the account holder.

@David42: That used to be true. But as one of the trade-offs for promising faster processing of checks, banks can now insist that checks meet specific physical requirements. Simply including the necessary information is no longer sufficient.

Even if a big check could be real, they probably aren't in practice. They're just for publicity.

When the payments are spread out, I think they establish an annuity, not a trust.

@keshlam: That doesn't mean the check isn't a real (i.e., legally valid) check.  It just means that banks may refuse to process it.

You are correct, your bank may reject a giant check because it does not meet the standards for automated processing. But I wouldn't want to assume I could give contest winners legally-valid giant checks and rely on the policies of banks to prevent them from being cashed. They do have mechanisms for dealing with checks which can't be processed automatically for whatever reason.

Spreading out the payments also increases the chances of the winner not going bankrupt in the end (as a LOT of lottery winners do)

RE: fine print--It is not unusual that an annuity from a lottery is not transferable, so a (lower) lump sum might be better if you want to then make a trust or leave it to e.g. grandchildren

Multimillion dollar checks in general are probably not going to be processed fully automatically, when that kind of money moves around it's worth a couple minutes of manual inspection by a bank employee.

I was on the receiving end of one of those cheques once, and I was very disappointed to learn it was basically a whiteboard, and they wiped off my name to use for the next guy. I really hoped I was going to get to keep it.

@Darren Hopefully you can use some of your winnings to purchase your own giant cheque whiteboard!

@ChrisBouchard It was a charity donation, sadly for me.
